# Can't add tags?

Tags: support, tags

This question: [Why does my SPI-using program in C give varying results?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8526/why-does-my-spi-using-program-in-c-give-varying-results) seems to scream "I should have the `spi` tag!".  Unfortunately there is no spi tag.

I believe the only way to create a tag is to use it in a question, so as a hack I tried to ask a fictional one temporarily, add the tag to the question above, and then delete mine.

However, my question would not go through -- "The tag spi is not allowed!" What's up with that? Privileges here lists the required rep as 150 (which the OP of that question does not have, or I would just have suggested it in a comment).

Comment: You could just edit the question to add the tag.

Comment: Does not work.  I am not able to create any *new* tags at all here by any means -- they are all "not allowed".  Presumably the feature has been locked out...

Comment: I have just noticed this myself. I was asking a question regarding the Sonic-Pi software which definitely needs a tag of its own. However, it said just that "The tag sonic-pi is not allowed!". Have we met some sort of tag cap? @Jivings could you help on this?